# Dynamics 365 (Business Central Cloud) Xmlport returns a different result depending on whether I retrieve it or not

Tags: dynamics-365, dynamics-business-central, dynamics-al

I have a Schrodinger code .

I have this Xmlport to import data. If I catch the result, it's always False and the data obviously is not committed. If I don't catch it, it works fine, there is no error raised and the data is correctly registered:

Catching it:

```
tempBlob.CreateInStream(inStreamObj);
if Xmlport.Import(idXmlport, inStreamObj) then begin
    // Never enters here!!!
    exit(true);
end else begin
    // Returns always False, nothing is imported.
    exit(false);
end;
```

Without catching it:

```
tempBlob.CreateInStream(inStreamObj);
Xmlport.Import(codigoXmlport, inStreamObj); // <- This works fine!
exit(true);
```

I need to catch the result because it's an automatic queue, I don't want it to raise an unmanaged error to stop the process. But is sabotaging me.

I have tested and debugged the 2 codes, same function, same parameters, I don't use globals... and the outcome is different by only making the call inside the conditional.

Comment: try something like this:if Xmlport.Import(idXmlport, inStreamObj) then begin
    // Never enters here!!!
    exit(true);
end else begin
 Message('%1',GetLastErrorText());
 exit(false);
end;

Comment: Thank you @serkanh i have tried it and i receive this error message: "An error occurred and the transaction was stopped. Please contact your administrator or partner for further assistance."

Comment: details of this kind of errors usually can be found in event log on windows or in app insight in azure